# Синтаксис: что значит команда %=

Tags: синтаксис, c++

Ребят что значит такая команда? Взять остаток и присвоить его переменной а?

```
a %= b;
```

как её можно записать более развёрнуто?
P.S. новичок в с++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да.

```
a = a % b
```